# How do i replace a character with number based on occurrence

Tags: java, stream

Let's say i have a String which is like `"Hello this is %d next year is %d"` or `"I am in %d and we will be in %d"`.

Now I have to replace first `%d` with current year and second `%d` with next year.

The final String should be

```
"Hello this is 2021 next year is 2022" 
"I am in 2021 and we will be in 2022".
```

I tried using split and streams, but that didn't really work.

The below approach didnt work

```
  List<String> myList= new ArrayList<>();
      myList.add("Hello is %d and %d");
      myList.add("Hello this is %d and %d");
      for(String s: myList)
      {
          String.format(s,2021,2022);
          System.out.println(s);

      }
```

Comment: Something like `String.format("Hello this is %d next year is %d", 2021, 2022)`?

Comment: @Pshemo I have a list of Strings in my case

  List<String> myList= new ArrayList<>();
       myList.add("Hello is %d and %d");
       myList.add("Hello this is %d and %d");
       for(String s: myList)
       {
           String.format(s,2021,2022);
       }

Comment: I tried the approach you suggested, which didnt actually quite work

Comment: *Strings are immutable* so `String.format(s,2021,2022)` doesn't *modify* `s` but creates new one based on received data. Then `String.format(s,2021,2022);` *returns* that new String. But it doesn't *print it automatically*, it is up to you what to do. Problem is you don't do anything with it. If you want to print it you can use `System.out.println(String.format(s,2021,2022));` or shorted `System.out.printf(s,2021,2022);`.